# Update progress bar using value present in an internal class

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, progress-bar

The two code segments below are in different namespaces.  And the second code's access modifier is internal. I'm doing some operations there and I want to calculate the percentage and update in the MgmntApp progressbar. How can I do this?

> WpfApplication1
>
> MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid Height="204">
        <ProgressBar Height="35" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="57,83,0,0" Name="progressBar1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="346" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I want to update the value of progress bar while doing a long-running operation in the class below.

> Different
>
> FileParser.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Different
{
    /// <summary>
    /// </summary>
    internal class FileParser:ImageFileParser
    {
        ImageFileParser.GenerateCmds()
        {
            percentage=change;    //0 to 100
            //long time operation
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If the parsing takes a long time you might want to run it on a separate thread.

You could raise an event on the FileParser when the progress changes and subscribe to this event in the MainWindow:

```
private void StartParsing()
{
    FileParser fp = new FileParser("FileName.txt");
    fp.ProgressChanged += FileParser_ProgressChanged;
    Thread t = new Thread(fp.GenerateCmds);
    t.Start();
}

private void FileParser_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // switch to the UI thread if fileparser is running on a different thread
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(
                              () => { progressbar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage; }));
}
```

To make this possible you need to add the event to the FileParser:

```
internal class FileParser:ImageFileParser
{
    internal event EventHandler<ProgressChangedEventArgs> ProgressChanged;

    ImageFileParser.GenerateCmds()
    {
        percentage=change;    //0 to 100
        OnProgressChanged(percentage);
        //long time operation
    }

    internal protected void OnProgressChanged(int percentage)
    {
        var p = ProgressChanged;
        if(p != null)
        {
            p(this, new ProgressChangedEventArgs(percentage, null));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But fp.GenerateCmds() will be called by one more class called PrgmCmdGen. How to update UI?(I'm not able to access progressBar1 of UI

Comment: Don't update the view from within the logic. Subscribe the PrgmCmdGen class to the event and expose another ProgressChanged event from the PrgmCmdGen class (just bubble the event up) and subscribe to it as I suggested in my answer.

Comment: new ProgressChangedEventArgs(percentage)); This is giving error. One more parameter UserState its asking.

Comment: just pass `null` or an object that you would like to pass on to the eventhandler.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just bind to a property of your *FileParser* class?

```
<ProgressBar Value="{Binding MyFileParser.PercentComplete}" ...
```

Then have *FileParser* implement *INotifyPropertyChanged*:

```
internal class FileParser:ImageFileParser, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private decimal _pct;
    internal decimal PercentComplete { 
        get { return _pct; }
        set {
            _pct = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("PercentComplete"));
        }
    }
    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));

    ImageFileParser.GenerateCmds()
    {
        PercentComplete = change;    //0 to 100
        //long time operation
    }
}
```

Then simply update the *PercentComplete* property as needed ...